# Late binding onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

Following part of my javscript(using jquery).

```
list = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
for(var i = 0 ; i< list.length ; i++) {
   $("<a>click here</a>").
      click(function(){
          foo(list[i]);
      }).
      appendTo('#sometag');
}
function foo(val) {
    console.log(val);
}
```

always prints c, no matter which tag you click on. How do I print proper value ???
It seems that it is using the last value of i=3 and thus evaluating o c always

Comment: Side note, `int i = 0` is wrong. Try `var i = 0` or just `i = 0`.

Comment: And technically, the code you have above doesn't even log "c", it logs "undefined". http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/9Th9G/

Comment: Dude it is just a sample code. People have already answered. Instead if finding mistakes above this, put some time below this.

Comment: Dude, post code that does what you say it does. It wastes everyone's time debugging your code when you post inaccuracies.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 6):

You'll need a <s>closure</s> new scope as the iteration finishes before the event handler is triggered, so when the click happens, the loop has finished and `i` is the last value it's set to, a new scope keeps the value of `i` local to that scope

```
list = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++) {

   (function(j) {

       $("<a>click here</a>").click(function(){
          foo(list[j]);
       }).appendTo('#sometag');

   }(i));

}

function foo(val) {
    console.log(val);
}
```

Another option is to add more jQuery

```
list = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

$.each(list, function(index, item) {
    $("<a />", {text : 'click here',
                on   : {
                    click : function() {
                        foo(item);
                    }
                }
    }).appendTo('#sometag');
});

function foo(val) {
    console.log(val);
}
```

Comment: I never thought of using the self executing function to form a closure. Good idea.  Is that preferable to forming the closure in a function defined elsewhere?

Comment: The event handler *already* is a closure. The solution is to create a new scope by executing a function, not by creating another closure.

Comment: @FelixKling - Yup, but most people tend to understand it better when you just say "closure", and not scope.

Answer (score 3):

Create a closure to retain the value of `i` for the particular iteration when the function is executed, without a closure `i` remains in scope causing all of the created functions to eventually have the value at the last iteration:

```
var list = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
for(var i = 0 ; i< list.length ; i++) {
   var func = createFoo(list[i]);
   $("<a>click here</a>").
      click(func).
      appendTo('#sometag');
}
function createFoo(value){
    return function(){
        foo(value);
    };
}
function foo(val) {
    console.log(val);
}
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/5dUgw/

**Also note** you need to change `int` to `var` since this is JS.

Comment: The event handler *already* is a closure. The solution is to create a new scope by executing a function, not by creating another closure.