# Javascript variable scope and object passed as argument to function

Tags: javascript, gulp, laravel-elixir

I'm using Laravel Elixir and Laravel-Elixir-SpriteSmith to create some sprite icons. I have at least 3 different icon sizes stored on different folders, so I tried to iterate over these folders and execute the task to generate sprites for each of them:

My problem is that in `cssOpts.cssSelector` function of the second argument passed to `mix.spritesmith` the value of `set`is always the last value.

The code explains it better:

```
var sources = [
        { size: 16, source: 'resources/bower_components/famfamfam-silk/dist/png' },
        { size: 22, source: 'resources/assets/icons/22' },
        { size: 38, source: 'resources/assets/icons/38' }
    ];

    for(var i in sources) {
        var set = sources[i];

        mix.spritesmith(set.source, {
            imgOutput: 'public/icons',
            cssOutput: 'public/css',
            imgName: set.size + '.png',
            cssName: 'icons-' + set.size + '.css',
            imgPath: '../../icons/' + set.size + '.png',
            cssOpts: {
                cssSelector: function(item) {
                    console.log(set.size); //PROBLEM HERE. Always prints 38! Should print 16 - 22 - 38.
                    return '.icon' + set.size + '-' + item.name.replace('_', '-');
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

What should I do to pass the right value to the function at each loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're experiencing is called *late binding*. You can read about it on multiple SO questions, for example this: [Late binding onclick event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21500071/late-binding-onclick-event)

You basically need to make a new scope, which will have a certain value of `set` bound to it.

```
cssSelector: (function(innerSet) {
    return function(item) {
        console.log(innerSet.size);
        return '.icon' + innerSet.size + '-' + item.name.replace('_', '-');
    };
})(set)
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the others, this is due to how closures and variable hoisting work in javascript : `var set` is part of the upper function scope, not the loop. So by the time `cssSelector` is executed, `set` is equal to the last element in the array.

You could use @ralh's way, or use the forEach method :

```
var sources = [{
    size: 16,
    source: 'resources/bower_components/famfamfam-silk/dist/png'
}, {
    size: 22,
    source: 'resources/assets/icons/22'
}, {
    size: 38,
    source: 'resources/assets/icons/38'
}];

sources.forEach(function (set) {
    mix.spritesmith(set.source, {
        imgOutput: 'public/icons',
        cssOutput: 'public/css',
        imgName: set.size + '.png',
        cssName: 'icons-' + set.size + '.css',
        imgPath: '../../icons/' + set.size + '.png',
        cssOpts: {
            cssSelector: function(item) {
                console.log(set.size); //PROBLEM HERE. Always prints 38! Should print 16 - 22 - 38.
                return '.icon' + set.size + '-' + item.name.replace('_', '-');
            }
        }
    });
})
```