# Why is function printing i: 6 instead of i: 5

Tags: javascript

This is driving me crazy, why is this function printing 5 times "i: 6" instead of "i: 5"?

```
for(var i=1;i<=5;i++){
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("i: " + i)
    }, i*1000)
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Late binding onclick event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21500071/late-binding-onclick-event)

Comment: Or are you asking why the last value that gets late bound is 6 specifically?

Comment: Yes why the last value is 6!?

Comment: @jonrsharpe nothing to do with *post*-incrementing. The same would happen if it was a pre-increment. In either case, it's just the increment part that is the issue. Or rather, it's just the logic if `i = 5` the loop continues, if `i = 6` the loop stops. Hence, why `i` is `6` after the end of the loop.

Comment: @VLAZ you and Simran answered my question, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because by the time it starts printing values, loop is already completed.

In last iteration(i==5), value of i increases because of i++.

So by the time value is printed, i is updated to value 6 instead of 5.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you're getting the value of `i` at the termination of the loop where `i > 5`. To print `i: 5` five times:

```js
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("i: " + i)
    }, i*1000)
}
```

Comment: Yes that's is true, but I needed some explanation why i gets to 6

Comment: @FelipeBriga the idea is that when you print the value, ``i`` would have the final value that terminated the ``for-loop`` which is ``6``. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks that's what I was looking for!